# How to loop through validation errors from server

Tags: reactjs

I am performing validation on the server with Node.js and sending the response back to the client

```
try {
  const response = await register(user);
  console.log(response);
} catch (ex) {
  if (ex.response && ex.response.status === 422) {
    const errors = ex.response.data.errors;
    this.setState({ errors });
  }
}
```

If I console.log(this.state.errors) I get:

```
(5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {name: "Name required"}
1: {name: "Name should be more than 3 characters"}
2: {email: "Invalid email address"}
3: {password: "Password required"}
4: {password: "Password should be at least 6 characters"}
length: 5
__proto__: Array(0)
```

I then want to just loop through all the errors and display them one underneath each other.

```
     {this.state.errors &&
        this.state.errors.map(error => <li>{error}</li>)}
```

But I get an error that says:

this.state.errors.map is not a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently sometimes `ex.response.data.errors` isn't an array, probably an object.
I would suggest you to not only check if `this.state.errors` exist, but also to make sure that it's an array.

```
{Array.isArray(this.state.errors) &&
    this.state.errors.map(error => <li>{error.name}</li>)}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I submit the form after using your code I get this: Error:`Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {name}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

Comment: @user10980228 I've edited my answer. Just replace `{error}` with `{error.name}`

Comment: Thanks, that works for name. But it doesn't list the email and password errors. Is there no way to just use {error} to list ALL errors without out having to do {error.name}, {error.email} and {error.password}

Comment: @user10980228 You could e.g. unify errors on the API side so it would return array of strings, not array of objects.